I want a verification of my proof but there is already a similar question.
I had come up with a proof of a question and I wanted the proof to be verified but there already is a post dealing with the same question but in that case the op is not asking for proof verification but rather just for an answer, although there are some answers for that post which I do understand, but they are totally different from the proof I came up with.
What will be the best thing to do.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine. See also EoQS policy.

welsome to mmse! include a link to your wqestion so that people will better help you
